# Repositoty Test error: Failed to load ApplicationContext @ComponentScan ANNOTATION type filter requires an annotation type: interface

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, junit, data-jpa-test

I have a Spring Boot application which includes `UserRepository`, it `extends JpaRepository` and marked as `@Repository`. I want to create a test class `UserRepository` which starts like that:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
class UserRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    void testFindByUsername_Ok() {
...
```

yaml configuration:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: user
    password: pwd
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

I have PostgreSQL database and want to use H2 as embedded DB for testing.

pom:
parent: spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.7
dependencies: h2 2.1.214, postgresql 42.6.0, junit-jupiter-engine 5.9.2 (all latest for March 2023).

While launching the test case, the following error occurs:

> Failed to load ApplicationContext. @ComponentScan ANNOTATION type
> filter requires an annotation type: UserRepository. I don't use
> @ComponentScan or @SpringBootApplication.

I tried using those annotations on test class and they didn't help:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("my.base.package.dao.repository")
@EntityScan("my.base.package.dao.model.")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

Package of test matches package of repository.
I cannot add `@SpringBootTest` on my test because it conflicts with `@DataJpaTest`:

> Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for
> test class UserRepositoryTest.

What am I missing here? How to sovle this problem: **Failed to load ApplicationContext @ComponentScan ANNOTATION type filter requires an annotation type**